# How set default text color for iOS when developing on RN

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, iosdeployment

When developing an application on React Native, it became necessary to set the color for all text in the application using native methods. In the case of android, this does not cause problems (we just set the desired color in the styles.xml) but what about ios? Is it possible to prescribe the text color somewhere in the info.plist?

Comment: You can use an extension of UILabel. ```extension UILabel {
    open override func awakeFromNib() {
        awakeFromNib()
        self.textColor = .red
    }
}
```

Comment: @RajaKishan Should I write this in the AppDelegate.m?

Comment: This is the swift code but you can find this code in obj-c and also you can swift code with obj-c and write this code in a separate file.